# Imagick tintImage colors aren't consistent

Tags: php, image-processing, colors, imagick

I'm having trouble with colors when using PHP's Imagick's `tintImage` function. On my local dev environment, everything looks fine, but in the production environment the colors are off.

In each of the examples below, I'll display the values I'm using, then the original image on the left, the "correct" version produced by the dev environment in the middle, and the "wrong" version produced by the production environment on the right.

### Examples:

`$image->tintImage("rgb(57, 32, 109)", "rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.9)");`

[image: original] [image: correct1] [image: wrong1]

`$image->tintImage("rgb(142, 43, 98"), "rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.9)");`

[image: original] [image: correct2] [image: wrong2]

`$image->tintImage("rgb(218, 21, 2)", "rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.9)");`

[image: original] [image: correct3] [image: wrong3]

`$image->tintImage("rgb(171, 25, 158)", "rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.9)");`

[image: original] [image: correct4] [image: wrong4]

I don't know why this happens. The PHP code driving the application is identical in the dev and prod environments. How would I go about diagnosing this issue?

Comment: what version of Imagick are you using? Tint was pretty much broken up until 3.4.0RC3

Comment: Ah, that's probably it -- 3.2.0~rc1-1 on prod, 3.4.3~rc2-2 on dev

Answer (score 1):

The assumption of colourspace when not specified changed at some point.

The newer versions assume `sRGB` if not specified. So, if the results from the newer version look correct, set `sRGB` colourspace immediately after opening images to make older versions work the same.

Conversely, if results from older versions look correct, set `RGB` colourspace immediately after opening to make new version work like old one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Immediately after loading the layer, I tried `$image->setColorspace(_)` as well as `$image->transformImageColorspace(_)`, trying both `Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB` and `Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB` for each (I tried them all separately, not at the same time). The only one to make a visible different on the prod server was transforming the colorspace to RGB, which made the "wrongness" even more pronounced: example 3 above becomes https://imgur.com/lDDTKJm.png .

Comment: There appears to be more than the colorspace at play here: on the dev server, transforming the colorspace to RGB and *not* performing the tint produces the same image as the prod server when performing the tint but *not* performing a colorspace transform. This appears to suggest that regardless of the wrongness of color profiles, the tint itself isn't happening on prod.